# Selective static member inheritance with CRTP

Tags: c++, static, crtp

so I have this class hierarchy using CRTP:

```
template <class T>
class A { 
  static Object x;
  static OtherObject y;
}

class B : public A<B> {
}

class C : public A<C> {
}
```

The original idea is that B and C do not share instances of x and y, since `A<B>` and `A<C>` are considered separate classes. But suppose that it was determined, for resource savings, that 'x' should be a singleton instance shared by B and C while an instance of 'y' shoul still be created for each derived class. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can make the class template derive from another class. Define `x` in the base class.

```
class ABase { 
  static Object x;
};

template <class T>
class A : public ABase { 
  static OtherObject y;
}

class B : public A<B> {
}

class C : public A<C> {
}
```